# Is is safe to append() to a slice from which another thread is reading?

Tags: go

Let's say I have many goroutines doing something like this:

```
func (o *Obj) Reader() {
  data := o.data;
  for i, value := range data {
    log.Printf("got data[%v] = %v", i, value)
  }
}
```

And one doing this:

```
func (o *Obj) Writer() {
    o.data = append(o.data, 1234)
}
```

If `data := o.data` means the internal structure of the slice is copied, this looks like it could be safe, because I'm never modifying anything in the accessible range of the copy. I'm either setting one element outside of the range and increasing the length, or allocating a completely new pointer, but the reader would be operating on the original one.

Are my assumptions correct and this is safe to do?

I'm aware that slices are not meant to be "thread-safe" in general, the question is more about how much does `slice1 := slice2` actually copy.

Comment: No values in Go are safe for concurrent read and write. Run your program with the race detector as an added verification.

Comment: @JimB Let's say I use `atomic.Value` for accessing the slice (e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/rKpIqZSWww). Does `append()` have any side-effects that would make it unsafe? The race detector doesn't report any problems there.

Comment: You can't rely on the order of operations appearing consistent between CPUs. One could write the new array value then increase the length while the other one sees the length increase before it sees the new value, resulting in a garbage read.

Comment: @ZanLynx I thought that if I do `data := o.data` I own a copy of the (ptr, len, cap) structure, so another CPU increasing the length of their own copy does not matter to me as a reader.

Comment: @LukášLalinský: that looks like it might be race free _as is_, but the Writer will have a logical race, in that concurrent calls will overwrite each other. It's also very fragile, in that you will have a race if you index into to the slice since the backing array may be shared.

Comment: @LukášLalinský: Yes, I guess you are correct. The length in each slice is independent.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in the question is unsafe because it reads a variable in one goroutine and modifies the variable in another goroutine without synchronization.

Here's one way to make the code safe:

```
type Obj struct {
   mu sync.Mutex // add mutex
   ... // other fields as before
}

func (o *Obj) Reader() {
    o.mu.Lock()
    data := o.data
    o.mu.Unlock()
    for i, value := range data {
      log.Printf("got data[%v] = %v", i, value)
    }
}

func (o *Obj) Writer() {
     o.mu.Lock()
     o.data = append(o.data, 1234)
     o.mu.Unlock()
}
```

It's safe for `Reader` to range over the local slice variable `data` because the `Writer` does not modify the local variable `data` or the backing array visible through the local variable `data`.

Comment: Cool, so this means that the "shallow copy" of the slice is safe from anything that `append()` does in the other goroutine? In practice, I'd use `RWLock` there, but it's great if this is guaranteed to work.

Comment: Yes, a reader using a shallow copy of a slice is safe from `append` in another goroutine. The `append` function does not modify a variable visible to the reader because it either writes beyond the portion of the backing array visible to the reader or it allocates a new backing array.

Comment: This is why the code above works: https://play.golang.org/p/uId7jAWPZH. In a nutshell, `append` reallocates the new slice to a new location all together. By capturing the old pointer, we are able to loop thru it.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late to the party, but if your use-case is frequent reads and infrequent writes, `atomic.Value` is designed to solve this:

```golang
type Obj struct {
  data atomic.Value // []int
  mu sync.Mutex
}

func (o *Obj) Reader() {
  data := o.data.Load().([]int);
  for i, value := range data {
    log.Printf("got data[%v] = %v", i, value)
  }
}

func (o *Obj) Writer() {
    o.mu.Lock()
    data := o.data.Load().([]int);
    data = append(o.data, 1234)
    o.data.Store(data)
    o.mu.Unlock()
}
```

This will generally be much faster than either a `Mutex` or an `RWMutex`.

Note that this will only work with data this is effectively a copy, which it is in this case because you can safely maintain a reference to the previous slice when appending, as `append()` creates a new copy if it extends. If you're mutating the elements of the slice, or using another data structure, this approach is not safe.